# Distância entre uma linha e um ponto no espaço tridimensional

Tags: java, array, matemática, geometria

Digamos que *existam três pontos num espaço 3D* (pontos `A`, `B` e `P`). Digamos também que existe *uma reta que passa por A e B*.

O que eu estou tentando fazer, na verdade, é descobrir se uma `reta AB` *intercepta* uma `esfera de raio r` que tem *origem em P*. Para isso eu só preciso checar se a distância da reta AB e do ponto P é menor que o raio da esfera.

```java
Vector A, B, P; //A minha classe Vector, guarda três valores (x, y e z)

if(distance(A, B, P) < r){
   return sphere.color;
}
```

**O meu problema é este método** `distance(Vector A, Vector B, Vector C)`... *Como eu posso calcular a distância de um ponto até uma reta (dada dois pontos da mesma), sendo que eu tenho que escrever isto em JAVA?*

> A distância entre um ponto e uma reta, é o comprimento de uma semirreta que começa em P, e termina na reta AB, formando um ângulo de 90 graus com a mesma.

Descobrir *a distância entre um ponto e uma reta*, desenhando por exemplo, é relativamente fácil, apenas *traçar uma reta saindo do ponto até a outra reta* e *medir o tamanho*.

Em 2D, isso seria fácil, já que a `reta D` (a distância) forma um triângulo retângulo, sendo a hipotenusa o `vetor V` que representa a posição do `ponto P`, e o cateto adjacente é este mesmo vetor projetado (que eu não sei o comprimento) na `reta AB`.

Desta forma eu poderia calcular a `reta D`, já que eu tenho meios de descobrir todos os três ângulos do triângulo (um deles é um ângulo reto, e o outro é a diferença dos ângulos da `reta AB` e o `vetor V`, e o terceiro completa 180 graus com os outros), eu posso usar o único lado que eu tenho o valor (a hipotenusa) e calcular o cateto oposto.

*Acontece que* eu estou trabalhando num ambiente *tridimensional*, onde não é tão simples achar um ângulo entre a `reta AB` e o `vetor V` para completar o triângulo. Além disso, *eu não sou matemático, e sim programador*, então eu queria um método de descobrir isso usando expressões algébricas (e métodos em Java), em vez de técnicas geométricas, de forma que funcionasse pra qualquer reta e ponto. Afinal a escrita matemática não é fácil de se converter em código de fato.

Por último, eu fiz esta postagem aqui, porque eu posso estar tentando achar a distância de um jeito desnecessariamente complicado, ou simplesmente errado.

Desde já, obrigado.

Comment: Me parece que você nem tentou criar uma solução, não procurou qual seria a expressão algébrica e nem tentou implementar nada do problema. Uma dica que eu te dou é: quebre os eu problema em parte de acordo com a teoria envolvida e traga apenas as partes que você não conseguiu resolver depois de tentar arduamente. Um outra dica é que leia o material: [**Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas** - Achar que nós faremos o seu trabalho todo de graça](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5486#5486).

Comment: No caso da expressão, não me parece relacionado a programação, você pode perguntar neste outro site do Stack Exchange: [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Sorack É relacionado a programação sim: aparentemente ele quer utilizar a função para resolver o problema mas não sabe como. Aparenta não saber usar a matemática e a função em Java em conjunto. Estou cogitando que esteja tendo dificuldades para identificar o problema. Talvez encaixe mais em um [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1202/839) do que o sugerido por você. Ele deve ter se encurralado na programação e achou que deveria perguntar como criar uma expressão algébrica em Java. Perguntou X (como fazer) mas disse que o problema é Y (a função). Vejo muito isso ao lecionar.

Comment: @Sorack Me perdoe se foi o que pareceu, mas eu não tenho intenção nenhuma de que _façam todo meu trabalho._ Eu irei editar a pergunta, para incluir mais detalhes de minhas reflexões sobre o assunto.

Comment: Depois de ver a resposta aceita, acredito que o @Sorack esteja correto. O texto dava a entender o contrário mas a resposta aceita aponta que a pergunta deve ser movida para o [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/), de fato.

Comment: Perguntas em português são aceitas no Mathematics? Se sim, a pergunta deveria ser movida. Se não, não vejo o problema de uma pergunta de um programador ser originária de um problema matemático. Quanto a resposta, alguém deveria edita-la usando Java (Meu Java está tão enferrujado que duvido que consiga produzir um código correto). Já recebi respostas em Matlab para perguntas em Python. Quanto ao edit na resposta original: matemática é essencial e talvez acelere seu tempo de desenvolvimento dar uma estudada no básico, principalmente algebra linear.

Comment: Se o problema fosse na implementação em Java estaria no [escopo do site](/help/on-topic), o que claramente não é o caso dada a resposta aceita. O fato de não ter um site específico para matemática em português por si só não faz com que o assunto passe a ser aceito aqui (assim como futebol, culinária e outros).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Digamos que existam três pontos num espaço 3D (pontos A, B e P). Digamos também que existe uma reta que passa por A e B."

O que eu estou tentando fazer, na verdade, é descobrir se uma reta AB intercepta uma esfera de raio r que tem origem em P. Para isso eu só preciso checar se a distância da reta AB e do ponto P é menor que o raio da esfera.

Logo, o que você quer descobrir é, dado uma reta **R** = [x,y,z]t + [a,b,c] (da uma olhada [aqui](https://brilliant.org/wiki/3d-coordinate-geometry-equation-of-a-line/) pra saber como escrever a equação. Você quer saber se ||**R** - **P**|| <= r

E resposta dessa inequação te da "t" onde a reta e esfera se interceptam, é de segunda ordem. Se houverem soluções reais a interseção existe, se não, não existe.

Comment: E onde entra o Java nisso?

Comment: O problema dele é matemático e não Java.

Comment: e aqui é um local para problemas de programação não matemática

Comment: Programação é matemática

Comment: Discordo. Em alguns pontos programação e matemática estão relacionados, mas uma definitivamente não é a outra.

Comment: Verdade, relacionar com igualdade é incorreto. O relacional correto seria contido

Comment: Mas uma das tags da pergunta é matemática, dar uma solução matemática é valido para a pergunta. Mas o local de perguntar ideal seria Mathematics, mas esse é o um fórum em inglês e achei que seria mais empático da minha parte dar a solução aqui mesmo.

Comment: Opinião como usuário e não como moderador: não vejo problema em ajudar o colega (muitas vezes faço isso, mas geralmente posto como wiki da comunidade ou em um site a parte tipo pastebin, quando é fora do escopo). Mas é importante entender o risco de tomar um negativo (que por acaso não é meu). Considerando que ele tira muito pouco da pontuação, acho que se a intenção é ajudar, é um preço válido a se pagar pelo problema do escopo. O mais importante mesmo é o fechamento da pergunta, assim o site não fica bagunçado, mas o autor nao sai sem solução.

Comment: Sobre o fato de ter a tag matemática, segue trecho do wiki da própria tag: _Quaisquer questões de matemática neste site devem ser relacionadas com a programação_

Comment: A pergunta é relacionada com programação. Problemas com programação podem surgir tanto de sintaxe, convenções e implementação quanto de lógica e matemática. Ainda assim achei a questão válida. E o preço é justo desde que o colega consiga resolver o problema dele.

Comment: o problema que eu tinha, que já foi resolvido, era que apesar de entender o assunto que eu estava tratando, na geometria, eu não conseguia imaginar ele dentro de um contexto de programação -- no caso em Java.

tipo, eu só tinha que desenhar uma linha que caisse na outra linha de forma perpendicular. Mas isto não significa nada pra mim sendo programador, e foi com isso que eu pedi ajuda. esta resposta em questão, nem foi tão definitiva (afinal ele me respondeu com uma verificação matemática _||R - P|| <= r_ mas a partir disso eu consegui construir o meu método.

Comment: Além disto, eu fiz uma pergunta parecida em um fórum de matemática, sobre coordenadas esféricas, que no fim se relacionava a programação, e lá recebi muitas críticas sobre exatamente isto. Por isso vim fazer esta pergunta aqui.

Até porque o motivo de eu querer uma forma numérica de representar o produto escalar que eu acabei usando, é porque eu tive que usar em Java, com programação.

Não existe nenhum modo de eu simplesmente escrever `vetor1.projetar(vetor2)`, eu tive que converter a explicação matemática do assunto e converter em código Java -- que foi  justamente o meu problema.